# React Router route not rendering component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to redirect my `HomePage` Component to a different component with one click of a button. However, when the link is clicked it's changing the path in the browser URL but I'm not able to see any change (i.e., my new `Addbook` component is not being rendered inside `Route`).

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./styles.css";
import HomePage from "./HomePage.js";
import Addbook from "./AddBook.js";
import {Router,Switch,Route, BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";

class App extends React.Component {

  render() 
  {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/"><HomePage></HomePage></Route>
            <Route path="/add"><Addbook></Addbook></Route>
        </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );  
  }

}

export default App;
```

**HomePage.js**

```
import React from "react";
import {BrowserRouter, Link, Router, Switch, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

class HomePage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return ( <div>
        <h1>Book Library</h1>
        <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
        <Link to="/add"><button id="addbook">Add Book</button></Link>
        <Link to="/search"><button id="searchbook">Search Book</button></Link>
        </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
        )
    }
  }
export default HomePage
```

**AddBook.js**

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const addBook =  () => {
    axios.post("http://localhost:3000/addbook",{
    name: this.state.name,
    author : this.state.author,
    date: this.state.date,
    category: this.state.category
    }).then(response => response.data).then(data => {
       console.log(data);
       if(data=="added")
       {
        
       }
    }, (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
}
class Addbook extends React.Component{
    render(){
       return (<div>    
        New Book<input type="text" onChange={(e)=>{
            this.setState({name: e.target.value})
        }} name="name" id="newbook"/>
        Author<input type="text" onChange={(e)=>{
            this.setState({author: e.target.value})
        }} name="author" id="Author"/>
        Date of Publish<input type="date" onChange={(e)=>{
            this.setState({date: e.target.value})
        }} name="date" id="dtofpub"/>
        Category<input type="text" onChange={(e)=>{
            this.setState({category: e.target.value})
        }} name="category" id="category"/>
        <button id="add" onClick={addBook}>ADD</button> 
        </div> )
    }
}
export default Addbook;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should update homePage like this :

```
import React from "react";
import {BrowserRouter, Link, Router, Switch, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

class HomePage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <div>
           <h1>Book Library</h1>
           <Link to="/add"><button id="addbook">Add Book</button></Link>
           <Link to="/search"><button id="searchbook">Search Book</button></Link>
        </div>
        )
    }
  }
export default HomePage
```

Answer (score 0):

There is syntax error please replace

> `<Route exact path="/"><HomePage></HomePage></Route>`

To

`<Route exact path="/" component={HomePage}></Route>`

Comment: I did that however here is not change still inside /add my AddBook component is not getting rendered